# Why are the contravariant and covariant basis perpendicular?

Tags: tensors, change-of-basis

Studying tensors, I get the concept of a contravariant and covariant vector, but my understanding is that a contra/covariant *basis* is different. Why are they perpendicular to each other or what is the motivation? Shouldn't the idea of the variance of a **vector** apply the same way to a basis **vector**?

On a similar note, why is it that the contravariant components are described by adding together the basis to form a vector, but covariant components are found by a dot product? What makes the dot product significant here?

Comment: vectors live in a vector space $V$ and covectors live in the dual       $V*=\{V\to{\Bbb R}:\ \mbox{which are linear}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are confusing three kind of pairing (dot products) among vectors and covectors.

If you pair a pair of vectors $v\cdot w$ is not the same if you pair a pair of covectors $\langle f,g\rangle$. But
in mixed case of pairing a pair, $f$ a covector and $v$ a vector, one can choose $f\bullet v=f(v)$.

But in case of choosing basis $b_k$ for $V$ and $\beta^l$ for $V^*$, is then when we have 
$$\beta^k(b_l)=\delta^k{}_l,$$
which the important device to access to the concepts and techniques about tensors.

Pairings enjoy the property of been bilinear maps i.e. rank two tensors.

Comment: another thing is as pair covectors (f,g) to get tensor of rank two: The tensor product $f\otimes g$ which can be reinterpreted as a bilinear map of the vector space working with a famous formula $$f\otimes g(v,w)=f(v)g(w).$$